# Perl Tk unable to return from MainLoop when implemented in a subroutine

Tags: perl, listbox, tk-toolkit

I am using the following code to display a list and get an array of selected entries from user.

```
#!/mu/bin/perl

use Tk; use strict; use warnings;
my @selections; 
my @choices = ("choice1", "choice2", "choice3", "choice4", "choice5", "choice6", "choice7", "choice8");

my $mw = MainWindow->new(-title=>"ListBox");
$mw->Label(-text => 'Select your choices')->pack();

my $lb = $mw->Listbox(-selectmode => 'extended');
$lb->insert('end', sort @choices);$lb->pack();
$mw->Button(-text => 'Select',
                   -command => sub {@selections = $lb->curselection;$mw->destroy;})->pack();
MainLoop;

foreach (@selections) {
    print $_."\n";
}
```

This code works fine on its own, after clicking the button, I am able to execute the print statements after `MainLoop;`. However, when I use this code (without the first 3 lines of course) in a subroutine called in my program, clicking the button only closes the GUI window, anything below the `MainLoop;` statement is not executed. The whole program just hangs as the subroutine is stuck in the MainLoop.

Any suggestion of what I might have done wrong and how can I fix this? Thanks.

Comment: Works fine here. I am using Ubuntu 15.10. I put your code except first 3 lines in a sub, and nothing odd happened.. Can you give some more details on how your sub looks like?

Comment: I have posted my subroutine in this thread http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1158589. It would be great if you could help me take a look.